# Installing WordPress only for a separate page - 'mydomain.com/blog'

Tags: plugins, themes, blog

So this may be a silly question but I already have my domain name and hosting. I have used it to set up my non-WordPress website complete with different pages and even an online library where you can register, login and download books.

Now I wanted to add a blog to it - basically when someone opens the 'blog' link from the menu it should lead them to a blog page - "mydomain.com/blog" where I'm using WordPress themes and plugins to style the page.

I didn't want to just create a blog item in the menu and link that to my WordPress blog.

I don't have any blog as of now and I was wondering if there's a way I could simply add a WordPress template and add plugins, thus creating a blog page using them for only a separate page on the website as opposed to the complete website?

If this isn't possible then is there possibly some way I can port all my code onto a WordPress download without changing the layout or the CSS except to enable the addition of a blog page with the WordPress theme enabled on it?

Comment: This question is a bit confusing.  What do you mean "for a separate page"?  How is that different than "www.mysite.com/blog" (where "/blog" is the directory in which you install your blog)?

Comment: So I edited the question. Hope that makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely possible. Say you have `domain.com`. You set up a WordPress installation in `domain.com/my-special-page`, and you will be able to access your WordPress site there.

You can ALSO set it up at `domain.com/my-special-page.php` if you really want to keep file name extensions, but it's more work, and an uglier URL, so I wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there's a way I could simply add a WordPress
>   template and add plugins...

If I am understanding this correctly, no. A WordPress install is all or nothing. You can't just install "templates". That would be like trying to use just the passenger seat of a car. It doesn't make sense and doesn't really work.

> If this isn't possible then is there possibly some way I can port all
>   my code onto a WordPress download without changing the layout or the
>   CSS except to enable the addition of a blog page with the WordPress
>   theme enabled on it?

You would have to convert your code into a WordPress theme, which really isn't that hard but if you know how to do that you wouldn't be asking.

You can use the WordPress backend without using any front end theming at all but you have to use your own code to pull and display the posts. I don't recommend it. It is difficult and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is done very frequently and is called an endpoint and not a page. Although most developers prefer to use subdomains for fresh Wordpress installs, endpoints are very common as well.

You can install a Wordpress blog at any endpoint within your domain/site. For example, you can use 'blog' or 'news' like this: mydomain.com/blog/ and mydomain.com/news/. Your endpoint can be even two levels deep, like this: mydomain.com/about/blog/.

To use endpoints do the following:

1. Create a folder, let's call it News
2. Drop all Wordpress files inside the News folder
3. Check your site's root .htaccess file for proper redirects
4. It's possible your root .htaccess has a index.php catchall redirect. If that's the case then you need to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` if it's not already there